# Plot Dataframe with Enums as values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, enums

I have some data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 5), (0, 2), (1, 4), (0, 1)])
```

First column should be enum:

```
class Type(Enum): 
    OFF = 0
    PARTIAL = 1
    FULL = 2
    def __str__(self):
      return self.name

data[0] = data[0].apply(lambda x: Type(x))
```

Now we have table:

```
         0  1
0  PARTIAL  1
1     FULL  1
2     FULL  5
3      OFF  2
4  PARTIAL  4
5      OFF  1
```

And I want to be able to plot that data easily, by command:

```
data.plot()
```

Is there any way to do that?
Because for now I need to split it to two dataframes and plot them separately:

```
data[0].apply(lambda x: x.value).plot()
data[1].plot()
```

Comment: Just to understand it correctly: You want the enum values again as integers in your plot?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but the solution is **not recommended**:

I created function, which checks if we have enum in dataframe and replace it with appropriate values:

```
  def plot_df(df, **input_data):
    if isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):
        df_copy = df.copy()
        for frame in df:
            if isinstance(df[frame].all(), Enum):
                df_copy[frame] = df[frame].apply(lambda x: x.value)
        df_copy.plot(**input_data)
    elif isinstance(df, pd.Series):
        df_copy = df.copy()
        if isinstance(df.all(), Enum):
            df_copy = df.apply(lambda x: x.value)
        df_copy.plot(**input_data)
    else:
        raise TypeError('data should be Dataframe or Series')
```

Now we add method to an existing object instance (which is not recommended):

```
import types
data.plot = types.MethodType(plot_df, data)
```

And now we can do:

```
data.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from enum import Enum


def plot_enum_df(df, **input_data):
    if isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):
        df_copy = df.copy()
        for frame in df:
            if isinstance(df[frame].all(), Enum):
                df_copy[frame] = df[frame].apply(lambda x: x.value)
        df_copy.plot(**input_data)
    else:
        raise TypeError('Data should be DataFrame')


def plot_enum_s(series, **input_data):
    if isinstance(series, pd.Series):
        s_copy = series.copy()
        if isinstance(series.all(), Enum):
            s_copy = series.apply(lambda x: x.value)
        s_copy.plot(**input_data)
    else:
        raise TypeError('Data should be Series')


def plot_enum_config():
    pd.DataFrame.plot_enum = plot_enum_df
    pd.Series.plot_enum = plot_enum_s
```

On the start of a code we should place:

```
plot_enum_config()
```

And now we can do:

```
data.plot_enum()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you already have an answer, I just wanted to add alternatives.

I assume here that you want to use Enums to organize your problem. The enums have a numeric structure and it makes sense to plot them as numbers in a line plot. Then to create a plot just with `data.plot()` I would use `IntEnum` like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
from enum import IntEnum

class Type(IntEnum):
    OFF = 0
    PARTIAL = 1
    FULL = 2

data = pd.DataFrame(data=[(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 5), (0, 2), (1, 4), (0, 1)])
data[0] = data[0].apply(lambda x: Type(x))

data.plot()
```

As an alternative you could use [pandas Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) to have something equivalent to enum in pandas, like so `data[0] = data[0].apply(lambda x: Type(x)).astype("category")`. But this does not help with your `data.plot()` problem directly.